# In Django, create a custom model.Field which stores the data like a CharField but behaves like a forms.DateField in the admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to create a custom `model.Field` called WeekField. The database field must be stored as an 8 character string in the `YYYYmmdd`. I have extended `models.CharField` for that:

```
class WeekField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WeekField, self).__init__(max_length=8, *args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        return Week(value)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return value.get_id()
```

The `Week` object referenced above has a constructor which can take either a date or a string in the format `YYYYmmdd`.

My problem is that in the admin, it shows up as a text field. How can I coerce the admin to treat it like a date field?

I tried adding this to my WeekField class, to no avail:

```
def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': forms.DateField}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(models.CharField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you subclass DateField instead and provide a get_prep_value/to_python that converts it to the text format you want to store in the database?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.get_db_prep_value

Comment: Would the ORM know to treat it as char field instead of a date field?

Comment: I tried making my custom field subclass `DateField`. Even though my get_prep_value returned a String, Django made the field a Date in the DB. I think I will go down this route though, as the value does not strictly need to be a string in the DB.